# mySQL query same column attribute

Tags: mysql

I've got this Database table:
[image]

I want to query all No Columns which have the same number.
So the final result should be:

```
ID  No    Name
1   53    Will
2   346   James
3   53    Someone
4   346    Elli
```

without `5 32 Mat` because "32" doesn't match anything else.

This is my query so far, but it doesn't work like I want it:

> SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `No` = `No`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (Simpler and faster) :

```
SELECT T1.* FROM test T1,test T2
WHERE T1.ID<>T2.ID  
AND T1.No=T2.No
ORDER BY T1.ID
```

Result:

```
ID  NO    NAME
1   53    Will
2   346   James
3   53    Someone
4   346   Elli
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5831a/7).

**EDIT:**
To see the last entries use this query:

```
SELECT T1.* FROM test T1,test T2
WHERE T1.ID<>T2.ID  
AND T1.No=T2.No
GROUP BY T1.No
ORDER BY T1.ID
```

Result:

```
ID  NO  NAME
3   53  Someone
4   346 Elli
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5831a/9).

Comment: works perfect! Is they are any change to remove the first entry, so the result in this example to be only 53 Someone; 346 Elli?

Comment: @user3066588: Its a pleasure, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with a subquery :

```
SELECT *
FROM Test
WHERE NO IN (
    SELECT NO
    FROM Test
    GROUP BY NO
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b061f/5

Comment: works perfect! Is they are any change to remove the first entry, so the result in this example to be only 53 Someone; 346 Elli?